# Translating a mesh with NinevehGL for iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to use [NinevehGL](http://nineveh.gl/) to display my `.obj` models in a `NGLView`.

I'm trying to translate a mesh, but instead, it's moving the camera even if I specify to translate instead moving.

So, for any of these methods I get unwanted results:

```
[_camera moveRelativeTo:NGLMoveLeft distance:0.001];
```

not appearing

```
[_mesh translateRelativeToX:0.001 toY:0 toZ:0];
```

not appearing

etcetera...

I'm trying to **translate** the mesh without changing the camera angle when I touch a position `(x,y)`.

How can it be done?

Thank you very much in advance.

---

**EDIT:**

I can move the mesh by:

```
_mesh.x = -(centerX);
_mesh.y = -(centerY);
```

but it's moving the camera as well. So to explain it better, when I "translate" my mesh (to up, down, left and/or right), it's "yawing". Yawing could be illustrated by this picture:

[image]

---

**MORE DETAILS:**

This is my current result:

https://media.giphy.com/media/QtG90VAyKckZG/giphy.gif

And this is what I really want.

https://media.giphy.com/media/3cDUBLOn3V0Lm/giphy.gif

Comment: Just one general suggestion: click to down load Unity3D (unity3d.com, downloads) (it's perfectly free for the normal license).  It's "incredibly easier" to tinker around with mesh, in Unity (after all, that's what it is made for).  it's usually easier to become an expert there and then figure out stuff in iOS/android libraries.  PS u should definitely be thinking in terms of z-forward.   (On a plane, car, humanoid character or any vehicle, or indeed any video game model at all, twist on x is pitch, twist on y is yaw and twist on z is roll.)

Comment: in your first example gif, is it possible you are rotating (not translating) the model BUT the logical center of the model is *not in the center of the model* ... in fact it's perhaps somewhere near the camera?  (Are you using Cheetah3D there for the model?  It's quite a nuisance to learn how to "shift the center" of models in modeling software.)

Comment: Hi @JoeBlow thanks for your answer. Unity3D has been my first thought to do this, but since I'm using C++ libraries and I'm not expert in Unity3D I discarded that possibility. In the past I put some jobs to make C++ libraries for Unity3D in Freelancer.com, and nobody was able to do it. Neither me. For the second answer, I know I'm really rotating, but basically I'm typing "translateTo" or "moveTo" based in the `_mesh`, not the `_camera`. It's still rotating my figure. That's the problem :\

Comment: Just for the record, in Unity you just use c#. It is absolutely trivial, it's like programming in basic. There is almost no difference from c or c++. It is ridiculously easy to program.  Anyway maybe someone on the "Nineveh" forum would have your answer here? There does not seem to be many/any Nineveh users here on SO  :O  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you... I'll give a try to port my libraries to Unity and see what happens

Comment: hi Rafael -- what sort of libraries do you mean? to do what?  Cheers

Comment: It's some sort of custom library of AR :)